# I have ubuntu, I installed windows 10 on vmware and it has no internet, how do I solve this?

Tags: vmware

So I have ubuntu, and I needed office on my laptop so I installed windows 10 in a virtual machine in vmware, and it has no internet.
I tried switching between the three modes: Bridged NAT and Host only, none of them gave me working internet.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use bridged NAT
Here a manual about bridged networking https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html

It looks like your laptop has multiple network adapters. You should bridge your VM with the network adapter that is connected to the network (either the ethernet or the wireless adapter)